# Can DPM 2010 protect computers in a trusted domain when there is no forest trust relationship?

Tags: active-directory, scdpm, cross-domain

Scenario: DPM 2010 is installed in a domain in a forest, while the servers to be protected are installed in a different domain in a different forest. The two domains are child domains in their respective forests.

There is a two-way external trust between the two domains, but there is no forest trust in place (nor can it be created).

Will DPM 2010 be able to protect servers in the other domain (mainly Sharepoint 2010 and Exchange 2010)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked Microsoft itself... they confirmed you need a full forest trust, a "simple" trust between the two domains is not enough.